# Command failed: git clone in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, npm-install, hyperledger-burrow

I'm currently new to Ubuntu, and blockchain. I'm trying to setup for a Hyperledger Burrow project on Ubuntu. Firstly, I clone the project from github, then install "snak" (a npm that helps you interact with Burrow blockchain) via command line:

```
npm install -g snak
```

It works, but when i check folder node_modules there's no snak npm. So I try again with this:

```
sudo npm install -g snak
```

This time there are some errors as below
[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if you check 3rd line from the bottom of the screenshot, you will see a permission denied error. Make sure .npm folder is owned by the user.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.npm
```

may fix this permission error.